# How to compute light time correction for eclipse entry/exit timings?

Tags: gmat, spice, lunar-eclipse

I used a typical geosynchronous orbital parameters and generated lunar shadow penumbra entry and exit timings using OREKIT and GMAT. GMAT has an option to include light-time correction (also for stellar aberration). The results generated by OREKIT are matching with GMAT when light-time correction is disabled. It is clear that OREKIT computes the timings by considering the geometry only. There is a brief on light time correction in this link https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/spkezr_c.html . Since there are two bodies involved here (Sun and Moon) with respect to Spacecraft, how to compute the correction factor.

Comment: You just compute the positions of each body by subtracting the light time distance from the time you pass into the ephemeris.  But the better way to do solar eclipses is to use Besselian Elements which already accounts for this.

Comment: Yeah, it is working. It is quite straightforward, thanks for the hint.